# Table of variations (tkztab) with n discontinuous points

Tags: tkz-tab

How could I draw the table of variations for a function with n discontinuous points ?

It would be something like the following MWE but with "*dots*" instead of hatching lines.
My function is `$x\mapsto \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \dfrac1{x-k}$`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz, tkz-tab}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzTabInit[lgt=1,espcl=1.5]{$x$ /0.8,  $f$ /2}{$-\infty$,$0$,$1$,$2$,$\dots$,$n-2$,$n-1$,$+\infty$}
\tkzTabVar{
    +       / $0$           / ,
    -D+     / $-\infty$     / $+\infty$,
    -D+     / $-\infty$     / $+\infty$,
    -DH     / $-\infty$     / ,
            /               / ,
    D+      /               / $+\infty$,
    -D+     / $-\infty$     / $+\infty$,
    -       / $0$           /
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `help` key to `\tkzTabInit` command to show predefined coordinates on the table  like this

```
\tkzTabInit[help,lgt=1,espcl=1.5]{$x$ /0.8,  $f$ /2}
{$-\infty$,$0$,$1$,$2$,$\dots$,$n-2$,$n-1$,$+\infty$}
```

This produce

[image]

You can after use those coordinates to place nodes wherever you want ( in your case between `(N51)` and `(N52)` )

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz, tkz-tab}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{h style/.style = {fill=none}} % hide hatching lines
\tkzTabInit[lgt=1,espcl=1.5]{$x$ /0.8,  $f$ /2}
{$-\infty$,$0$,$1$,$2$,$\dots$,$n-2$,$n-1$,$+\infty$}
\tkzTabVar{
    +       / $0$           / ,
    -D+     / $-\infty$     / $+\infty$,
    -D+     / $-\infty$     / $+\infty$,
    -DH    / $-\infty$    ,
      /      /         ,
    D+      /               / $+\infty$,
    -D+     / $-\infty$     / $+\infty$,
    -       / $0$           /
}
\path (N51)--node{$\ldots$}(N52);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]